# No-pictures buildings in Japan (shooting from street forbidden by law)

Tags: legal, japan, photography, officials

I often take pictures of buildings. Usually without knowing what the building is.

**QUESTION:** Are there buildings in Japan that it is forbidden by law to take pictures of?
If yes, which ones?

- Bonus for answers that cite laws/decrees as a reference, rather than speculation.
- This question is about law, not about etiquette.
- My pictures never include any humans: I pay special attention to only take buildings.
- This question is only about pictures taken from the street sidewalk, not in shops/etc.
- I am not using a flash.

Example for the UK: Under the law of the United Kingdom one cannot prevent photography of private property from a public place, except two places defined by law.

---

My question is different from [Taking photos in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7687) because:

- My question is about buildings shot from the street. The question there is very general, and the answer is mostly about taking pictures of **people**, or **inside shops**.
- My question asks for official laws/decrees. The question there is about [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) and [local-customs](/questions/tagged/local-customs), which is very different: its goal is **politeness**. My goal is to not end up in **jail**.

Comment: In almost every country, you'll have buildings that authorities do not want you to take pictures of, usually military and police facilities, but even public places [can be controversial](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/may/18/photography-glasgow-ban-subway).

Comment: @choster: Exactly, and I want information on what is OK and what is not. Most countries have laws/decrees for this, the trick is to find the relevant text (probably in Japanese). Your link talks about inside the subway (ruled by the transportation authority), whereas I am asking about street photography (rules by public law I guess?). Cheers!

Comment: maybe the problem wasn’t the building at all, you mention taking pictures of the entrance and some places have  a very strong privacy policies and that may have been the problem although there are some buildings were you should refrain picture as choster mentions military and police facilities, but even public places can be controversial

Comment: @JJCS: I would like to make it clear that my question is not about privacy, it is about law. Taking pictures of the entrance of a love hotel is not great from a privacy point of view (nobody want to be seen entering it), but it is not forbidden by law.

Comment: @nic In many places, privacy is protected by law.

Comment: @cpast: Let's focus the question on buildings. Anyway, all laws preventing buildings pictures are accepted as answers, regardless of whether they are actually privacy laws or not. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe check Google street view to see if any sensitive buildings are blurred out? A picture in street view doesn't mean it's legal, but I imagine the Japanese authorities know about it and would contact Google if they didn't like it.

Comment: @yellowantphil: I would not bet on that. The following Google Street View image is not from Japan, but from my home town in Norway and has been online for several years. And yes, the leftmost of the two yellow, blurred signs says 'photography prohibited'. https://www.google.de/maps/@59.965458,11.052058,3a,84.7y,270.59h,91.49t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sM17-R6_q95gwRBJfHPXmnQ!2e0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking photos in Japan](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7687/taking-photos-in-japan)

Comment: Something tells me that buildings the government doesn't want you to be taking pictures of wouldn't be aggregated into a big list by the government either..

Comment: @easymoden00b: The UK has such a list, though.

Comment: @cpast: That is true, however laws protecting privacy often only play a role once the photos are *published* (for which case it is always possible to blur out any people, if the objective of the photo is the building, anyway). Laws or otherwise regulations thought to be required for security purposes (no matter how absurd such restrictions are, given that taking photos with a good zoom from a bit farther away is usually still perfectly possible) usually attempt to prevent taking the photo in the first place.

Comment: @nic if you haven't noticed the UK has lost the plot in recent years.

Answer (score 9):

The only case I'm aware of where it's actually **illegal** to photograph something from a public place is when that something is a US military base or affiliated facility in Japan.  Here's the [Mutual Cooperation and Security Treaty under Article VI Facilities and Areas and the Special Criminal Act Attendant upon the Enforcement of the Agreement Regarding the Status of United States Armed Forces in Japan](http://law.e-gov.go.jp/cgi-bin/idxselect.cgi?IDX_OPT=3&H_NAME=&H_NAME_YOMI=%82%A0&H_RYAKU=1&H_CTG=1&H_YOMI_GUN=1&H_CTG_GUN=1&H_NO_GENGO=S&H_NO_YEAR=27&H_NO_TYPE=2&H_FILE_NAME=S27HO138) (phew!):

> 日本国とアメリカ合衆国との間の相互協力及び安全保障条約第六条に基づく施設及び区域並びに日本国における合衆国軍隊の地位に関する協定の実施に伴う刑事特別法
>
> 第六条
>
> 合衆国軍隊の機密（合衆国軍隊についての別表に掲げる事項及びこれらの事項に係る文書、図画若しくは物件で、公になつていないものをいう。以下同じ。）を、合衆国軍隊の安全を害すべき用途に供する目的をもつて、又は不当な方法で、探知し、又は収集した者は、十年以下の懲役に処する。

Basically, violating the "confidentiality" (機密) of a US Army base by providing "documents, diagrams, etc" with a "purpose" of harming the Army is punishable by up to ten years in prison.

Now you might well reasonably object that that doesn't say anything about photography, but this is apparently how the bases' well-posted ban is justified.  And if you're tempted to argue the point with the military police who'll come stop you if you try, bear in mind that Article 2 of the same law also makes it an unambiguous crime not to GTFO promptly when told to do so, with a  maximum penalty one year in prison.

And, while I can't prove a negative, that's it, although I understand a similar restriction applies to Japanese <s>army</s> self-defence forces bases as well.  There are plenty of owner-imposed restrictions on indoor photography in private places, and the aforementioned privacy restrictions that make publishing identifiable photographs of anybody tricky, but neither of these is a matter of criminal law.  (Assuming, again, that you cease, desist & leave when told to do so and thus don't become a trespasser.)

Comment: Let's try to abbreviate that: the MCSTA6FASCAAEARSUSAFJ. Hmm, that isn't much better.

Comment: Great find! Any similar document for the SDF maybe? And any other building is OK to be taken from the street, if I understand correctly? For instance bridges, dams, non-Army government buildings, etc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As said, I can't prove a negative, but as far as I know, everything else is OK.